# return false not working in my form

Tags: jquery, forms

Form should not submit with empty fields but it still submit(((
I need your help!

```
$(".wpcf7-form").submit(function(e) {
        var ref = $(this).find("[required]");
        $(ref).each(function(){
            if ( $(this).val() == '' ){

                alert("Required field should not be blank.");
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });  
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: You're returning from the anonymous function in `each()`, not the one in the `submit` handler. See the duplicate for a fix

Comment: Just a suggestion, since you already applied 'required' attribute into the fields, why don't just add a polyfill to make it work across all browser? 
This required attribute already work at most modern browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your help!